# Perfino agent failed to start on linux machine

Tags: linux, agent, javaagents, perfino

I tried to start perfino agent on linux machine using various ways. I also followed recommended instruction from perfino  more times. It still failing. Please help me. Please see below error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# -javaagent:perfino.jar=server=192.168.9.30,name=TestLinux,group=MAIN
bash: -javaagent:perfino.jar=server=192.168.9.30,name=TestLinux,group=MAIN: command not found...
```

Answer (score 0):

The "-javaagent..." string you are trying to execute directly is a VM parameter that you have to add to your java invocation.

Comment: My VM is linux server and it requires to connect the Perfino server. Please help me.

Comment: COuld you please instruct me, how to add on java invocation in linux?

Comment: Please read https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/perfino/help/doc/main/monitoring.html